# Windows "run" command doesn't find powershell anymore

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7-x64

My 'run' command doesn't find the Powershell or the PowerShell ISE anymore. I'm working on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

[image: error message]

The same story appears when I try to open a Powershell through the Windows explorer by typing `powershell` in the address bar. It works perfectly with CMD, but not with the Powershell.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: This isn't programming related, you need general computer support and should post on Superuser instead.

Comment: Sry, didn't know this! Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your environmental variables Path. It's possible it's been modified and the powershell path is no longer listed.

Comment: You are actually right - due to modifications in the path variable, a semicolon was deleted and the path not found. I checked the path a 100 times, but didn't recognized it! :) thanks